# Register scheduled task with New-ScheduledTaskTrigger to trigger on event ID

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

**Register-ScheduledTask with New-ScheduledTaskTrigger on a Windows event ID**

Hello Stack-overflow users. Neither MSDN nor Google yields results...
I configured a couple of scheduled tasks via a Powershell script. The scheduled tasks are set to run at certain times.
This all works fine. But I need to configure another scheduled task which run when a certain event ID is logged in the Windows event logger.
I can set this up manually of course but I want it as part of my automated script.

this is the code I have so far for the scheduled tasks, I need to replace the *$Trigger= New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -At 4:00am -Daily* section:

```bsh
        Copy-Item "\\networkDrive\Backups\scripts\Reset-Sessions.ps1" "c:\scripts\Reset-Sessions.ps1"
        $Trigger= New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -At 4:00am -Daily
        $User= 'Nt Authority\System'
        $Action= New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "Powershell.exe" -Argument "-executionpolicy bypass -File c:\scripts\Reset-Sessions.ps1"
        Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Reset-Sessions" -Trigger $Trigger -User $User -Action $Action -RunLevel Highest -Force
```

I have changed some of the directory and file names for online purposes.

I would appreciate it if somebody could steer me into the right direction or assist with an example.
I would prefer to only change the $Trigger portion and not re-write the whole script but I would understand if it is not possible.

I use Powershell version 5.1.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is helpful, because it uses a COM object approach, but I found [this](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1030490-task-scheduler-vb-script-help?page=1#entry-4758670) about the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step1**:
Go to eventvwr, then create a new scheduled task based on an eventid.

**Step2**:
Open powershell, then show the scheduled task and see the the way how to was written.

**Step3**:
Attached and test it in your scrip.

I created a temporary  Get-ScheduledTask and run the below line : all what you have to do is to replace the Subscription to meet your requirement.

```
$A = (Get-ScheduledTask "Tmp" | select -ExpandProperty Triggers)
```

Comment: Thank you, this works great on my Windows 10 computer, but I now see that I have another problem. The server where I want to run my script on is still a Windows 2008 R2 server which does apparently not support that "Get-ScheduledTask" module. However, this pointed me to some new information which I am looking into now. I will give feedback soon.

Answer (score 5):

With [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57559648/2716218) as a base and [some additional help](https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/3882c805-be26-416c-b636-8502d3fb877f/eventtriggered-task-via-powershell?forum=Offtopic) I was able to construct this script

```
    $taskname="Reset-Sessions"
    # delete existing task if it exists
    Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName $taskname -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |  Unregister-ScheduledTask -Confirm:$false
    # get target script based on current script root
    $scriptPath=[System.IO.Path]::Combine($PSScriptRoot, "Reset-Sessions.ps1")
    # create list of triggers, and add logon trigger
    $triggers = @()
    $triggers += New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtLogOn

    # create TaskEventTrigger, use your own value in Subscription
    $CIMTriggerClass = Get-CimClass -ClassName MSFT_TaskEventTrigger -Namespace Root/Microsoft/Windows/TaskScheduler:MSFT_TaskEventTrigger
    $trigger = New-CimInstance -CimClass $CIMTriggerClass -ClientOnly
    $trigger.Subscription = 
@"
<QueryList><Query Id="0" Path="Microsoft-Windows-NetworkProfile/Operational"><Select Path="Microsoft-Windows-NetworkProfile/Operational">*[System[(EventID=4004)]]</Select></Query></QueryList>
"@
    $trigger.Enabled = $True 
    $triggers += $trigger

    # create task
    $User='Nt Authority\System'
    $Action=New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "Powershell.exe" -Argument "-ExecutionPolicy bypass -File $scriptPath"
    Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $taskname -Trigger $triggers -User $User -Action $Action -RunLevel Highest -Force
```

The main magic is to use `Get-CimClass` to get the correct instance, and then populate `Subscription` from `Get-ScheduledTask "Tmp" | Select -ExpandProperty Triggers`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method I used in the end to solve the problem:
If you are trying to do this on a Windows Server prior to Server 2012 then you probably don't have the *Get-ScheduledTask* and *New-ScheduledTaskTrigger* and the *Register-ScheduledTask* modules on your Windows system. That means the script in my original question and the accepted answer won't work.

- A workaround is to create the desired scheduled task manually and then export it to a xml file. You can edit this file if you like, it is normal plain text xml.
- Then have your script and the xml file in the same directory.
- Change your script to be compatible with the older version of Powershell to import the xml file.

```
                schtasks /create /tn "Reset-Sessions" /xml "c:\scripts\Reset-Sessions.xml"
```

Your new scheduled task should now be registered and active.